# Adding data to database

Tags: magento2, database, model, forms

I'm able to fetch data from custom form but not able to put it in database table.

```
    $model = $this->_name->create();
    $entity = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $model->addData([
        "entity_id" => $entity['entity_id'],
        "customer_id" => $entity['customer_id'],
        "position" => $entity['position'],
        "department" => $entity['department']
    ]);

    $saveData = $model->save();

    if($saveData)
    {
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess('Record Inserted...!');
    }
    else
   {
      $this->messageManager->addSuccess('Record Inserted...!');
   }
```

**SimpleMagento\Custom\Model\Name.php**

```
class Name extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
```

{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('SimpleMagento\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\Name');
    }
}

**SimpleMagento\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\Name.php**

```
class Name extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
```

{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init("new_info","entity_id");
    }
}

**SimpleMagento\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\Name\Collection.php**

```
class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
```

{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init("SimpleMagento\Custom\Model\Name","SimpleMagento\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\Name");
    }
}

Comment: aside from there being no difference between the `$saveData` and `!$saveData` in your example, I'd advise you wrap `$model->save();` in a `try {$model->save();} catch (\Excpetion $e) {//log $e->getMessage();}` and see if there is an exception thrown

Comment: can you share this complete files

Comment: Can you share Error lines